# How to use react admin AutoCompleteInput with remote data?

Tags: autocomplete, remote-server, react-admin

I'm using react admin to develop a new panel for my client. I want to use `AutoCompleteInput`. But all the examples I find in the docs and online are showing a simple static data that is defined in the same component.

I want to use `AutoCompleteInput` for a list of items that is retrieved from my API.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the AutocompleteInput inside a ReferenceInput as explained in the documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#autocompleteinput

```
import { AutocompleteInput, ReferenceInput } from 'react-admin';

<ReferenceInput label="Post" source="post_id" reference="posts">
    <AutocompleteInput optionText="title" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

It means you have to declare the referenced resource using a `Resource` component in your admin.

If you want to fetch data directly from a remote source, then I suggest you use the Autocomplete from material-ui instead. React-Admin is not a UI library.